# Android Studio won't let me set up TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am not sure why this code doesn't work.  I am trying to make a choose your own adventure game.  The text describing your situation are text views, yet I cannot set them up.  Android Studio says that findViewByID() cannot be resolved.

```
package com.blogspot.darokrithia.dungeonfungeon;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static int row = 1;            //current row of room
    static int column = 1;         //current column of room
    static int totalRows = 5;      //total number of rows (including blank rooms)
    static int totalColumns = 5;   //total number of columns (including blank rooms)
    static Layout dungeon = new Layout(totalRows,totalColumns);    //Layout of this
    static Room currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,column);         //The rooms the player is in

    TextView roomText = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.RoomDescriptionText);    //What the room says
    TextView aOption = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.AOptionText);     //What option a does right now
    TextView bOption = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.BOptionText);     //What option b does right now
    TextView cOption = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.COptionText);     //What option c does right now
    TextView dOption = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.DOptionText);     //What option d does right now

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  // No fucking idea what this does, but android studio seems to need it.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);

        currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,column);
    }

    public void aButtonCLick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.AButton){
            dungeon.optionA(currentRoom);
        }
    }
    public void bButtonCLick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.BButton){
            dungeon.optionB(currentRoom);
        }
    }
    public void cButtonCLick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.CButton){
            dungeon.optionC(currentRoom);
        }
    }
    public void dButtonCLick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.DButton){
            dungeon.optionD(currentRoom);
        }
    }

    public Room getCurrentRoom(){
        return currentRoom;
    }

    public static boolean canMove(int direction){      //makes sure there is no zero room (A wall / blank room) in the direction you want to go
        Room testRoom;
        switch (direction){
            case 1:
                testRoom = dungeon.getRoom((row-1),column);
                if(testRoom.getRoomID() == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            case 2:
                testRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,(column-1));
                if(testRoom.getRoomID() == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            case 3:
                testRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,(column+1));
                if(testRoom.getRoomID() == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            case 4:
                testRoom = dungeon.getRoom((row+1),column);
                if(testRoom.getRoomID() == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void moveNorth(){    //moves up one row
        if(canMove(1)){
            row -= 1;
            currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row, column);
        }
    }
    public static void moveEast(){     //moves across one column
        if(canMove(2)){
            column -= 1;
            currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,column);
        }
    }
    public static void moveWest(){     //moves back one column
        if(canMove(3)){
            column += 1;
            currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,column);
        }
    }
    public static void moveSouth(){    //moves down one row
        if(canMove(4)){
            row += 1;
            currentRoom = dungeon.getRoom(row,column);
        }
    }


}
```

I know that this isn't a lot of code, so if you need more context, I am willing to copy paste my entire code into here.  I also have made sure that TextView is imported.

Comment: In what type of class is this code written ? Can you post the whole class ?

Comment: My main Activity, I am putting in the code

Comment: Actually, don't botter, Tanis already found the typo ;)

Comment: Please also take ninetwozero's answer into consideration, or you'll encounter another problem .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) has a lower-case "d" at the end.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct, I will mark this as the answer in 11 minutes when it lets me.  I feel like a doofis.  Thank you

Comment: A good practice is using code completion from your IDE whenever you can. Less typos, more productivity, less frustration, more happiness ;)

Comment: Interestingly, my flag to close this post because it was due to a typographical error, was declined.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to call `findViewById(int)` in your `onCreate(Bundle)` method, after setting the content view (via `setContentView(int)`).

Otherwise you'll possibly get a `NullPointerException` down the road due to the fact that the views haven't been created when the variables are set.